# I'm trying to figure out who the artist is on a painting. I don't know if it's Chinese or Japanese (Characters identified: 新羅山人 秋岳)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

This is a signature on a watercolor painting.  I'm trying to figure out who the artist is. I don't know if it's Chinese or Japanese. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image] [image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Artist name transcription]

The artist used two [courtesy names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtesy_name) in the piece:

- One in the calligraphy, 新羅山人;
- One in the seal, 秌（秋）（岳）.

The artist's real name is [「華嵒」 (Mandarin Pinyin: **Huà Yán**)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hua_Yan), a [Qīng Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qing_dynasty) painter.

---

#### Notes on seal character identification

In the seal,

- 「秋」 uses the variation 「秌」, where 「禾」 and 「火」 are switched around;
- 「岳」 is written with a shape like

  <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
  [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
  [image]
  [鐵](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)267.4
  [合集14423](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=14423&jgwfl=)</kbd>

  where the middle peak of [「山」 (*picture of a mountain with multiple peaks*)](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=856) is exaggerated, and [「丘」 appears in its historical form (*picture of hills with multiple peaks*)](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=161) (glyph evolution below):

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [佚](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)733
  [合集5602](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=5602&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[齊](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi_(state))
  [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
  [image]
  子禾子釜
  [集成10374](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=10374&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
  [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
  [image]
  封診式47
  [睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>[西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han)
  [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
  [image: 岳]
  縱橫157
  [馬王堆帛書](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mawangdui_Silk_Texts)</kbd>
  <kbd>[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
  [image: 丘]</kbd>